# Responsive Header Implementation in Mantine (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mantine

I'm new to React (especially Typescript) and I was wondering how to pass these interface props correctly to this Navbar component in my main App?

```
interface HeaderResponsiveProps {
  links: { link: string; label: string }[];
}
export default function Navbar({ links }: HeaderResponsiveProps) {
```

```
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'

export default function App() {
  return (

      <Navbar links={???}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it inside your `Navbar` component, like this:

`function Navbar(props: HeaderResponsiveProps ) { [your component] }`

Alternativelly using destructure would be like:

`function Navbar({ links }: HeaderResponsiveProps ) { [your component] }`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response! That's how I have it declared, but I'm confused about how to initialize the component with props in my main App.

Comment: The way you've declared the interface means that it should start with something like `<Navbar links={[{link: "https://example.com", label: "your label"}]} />`, i don't know if was about this you were wondering

Comment: Makes sense now, I wasn't using the array syntax correctly. That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.